# How can I normalize timezones when comparing two Java Calendars?

Tags: java, calendar

I'm furious with the 7th of November.

I've written a method to calculate the number of days between two Java Date objects (before it gets mentioned, JodaTime is not an option) -- the method works the majority of the time, but when the start xor end date occurs during daylight savings time, the output is off by a day.

Do Calendars have some way of overriding the timezone of dates? I don't care what timezone the dates are actually in, but they need to be the same one!

Code below:

```
public int getDayRange() {

        //startDate = "Sat Nov 06 00:00:00 EDT 2010";
        //endDate = "Sun Nov 07 23:59:59 EST 2010";

    TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC");

    GregorianCalendar cal1 = new GregorianCalendar(tz); 
    GregorianCalendar cal2 = new GregorianCalendar(tz); 

    cal1.setTime(startDate);
    cal2.setTime(endDate);

    long ms1 = cal1.getTime().getTime(); 
    long ms2 = cal2.getTime().getTime(); 
    long difMs = ms2-ms1; 
    long msPerDay = 1000*60*60*24; 

    double days = difMs / msPerDay;

    return (int) Math.floor(days)+1;
        //returns 3(!!!) days (wrong)
}
```

Comment: This would be much easier if you used JODA time ;)

Comment: @LouisWasserman Would be, but not possible, unfortunately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Never try to count days using 1000*60*60*24 as a day.  It's just plain wrong.  If you really need to implement the calculation yourself for some reason, use the YEAR and DAY_OF_YEAR fields on the Calendar to count differences in actual days.

You cannot simply "override" the timezone of a `java.util.Date` because it has no timezone information associated with it.  You need to know what timezone it was intended to be interpreted in, and use that timezone when converting it to a human representation.  Arbitrarily using UTC to interpret it will, as you have discovered, not deliver consistent results!

```
  public int getDayRange() {

        //startDate = "Sat Nov 06 00:00:00 EDT 2010";
        //endDate = "Sun Nov 07 23:59:59 EST 2010";

    TimeZone tz1 = TimeZone.getTimeZone("EDT");
    TimeZone tz2 = TimeZone.getTimeZone("EST");

    GregorianCalendar cal1 = new GregorianCalendar(tz1); 
    GregorianCalendar cal2 = new GregorianCalendar(tz2); 

    cal1.setTime(startDate);
    cal2.setTime(endDate);

    if (cal1.get(Calendar.YEAR) == cal2.get(Calendar.YEAR)) {
        return cal2.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) - cal1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) + 1;
    } else {
        //this gets complicated, but you can see what to do, plenty of examples online
    }

  }
```

Comment: +1. The time zone is crucial to compute a difference in days. The same dates (i.e. moments) could be on the same day in Australia, but on separate days in France, for example.

Comment: +1 its important to understand that a Date is simply the number of milliseconds elapsed since Jan 1, 1970, 00:00:00, UTC. As stated, there is no timezone information associated with a Date - you only get a timezone when you format one. I see this question so often that I finally wrote a blog post about it - see http://greybeardedgeek.net/2012/11/24/java-dates/

Comment: However, I don't know beforehand which timezone the start or end date will be in. Does this mean the only way to handle this would be to always track times as UTC internally?

Comment: @RavenDreamer: then computing the number of days between the dates doesn't make much sense. Two dates with a 1 second difference could be on two separate days in a time zone, and on the same day in another time zone.

Comment: Are they sourced internally?  Are they user input?  How are they getting parsed into java.util.Date-s?  If it's the user's timezone, it's actually likely going to be like "America/New_York" which will sort the EDT vs EST difference automatically, you wouldn't need to actually have two different ones for the Calendars as in the example.  If it's a web-app and you have to differentiate between user time and JVM time and you're not using any framework to help get things parsed consistently, you are in for a world of hurt.

Comment: @JBNizet The dates will always be from the same timezone (the local user's, so EST for me), but whether or not DST is activated depends on where in the year the date falls.

Comment: @Affe They are sourced externally.

Comment: So, use two Calendars and set their timezone to DST, then check the difference in days between those two Calendar instances.

Comment: Assuming its a client application (Swing, Android, whatever) then the System TimeZone should be one that automatically handles DST switchovers, but it still matters that the method used to conver input to java.util.Date is consistent with the method used to interpret java.util.Date as human times.

Answer (score 1):

Your system should store all timestamps in UTC!
If not you will never get that to work!
Then the difference calculation is simple.

If you need to display localTime too, you have to store the TimeZone together with the date as a pair:  Example: (long timeUtc, int timezoneOffSetToUtc). 
The timezoneOffSetToUtc is the offset valid at the creation date of the pair.

The TimeZone should only be instantiated from String like ("Austria / Vienna").